# How To add and remove the fields from the nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to add a new field & also need to remove the field from the nested field.

Here is my mapping

```
PUT nestedtest/_mapping/nestedtype
{
  "properties": {
    "name":{
      "type": "text"
    },
    "address":{
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "city":{
          "type":"text"
        }
      }


    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to add a new field in the `**address nested path`**, like **country = India`**
And then I need to remove the data present in the country field i..e **India** not the country field

I tried with this

```
POST /nestedtest/nestedtype/1/_update?pretty
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source.address=params.country",
    "params": {
      "country":{
        "country":"India"
      }
    }

  }

}
```

But this is removing the previous field **city** from the **address** nested path.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `doc` method instead of the `script` one.

```
  POST /nestedtest/nestedtype/1/_update?pretty
  {
      "doc":{
           "address":{
                  "country":"India"
           }
      }
  }
```